# Camera parameters adjusting failed issue in stitching detail

Tags: opencv, camera, opencv-stitching

I am using stitching_detaild.cpp sample code from opencv. When I tried to stitch free hand images it worked. But when I kept camera at constant angle and just moved image then I am getting Camera parameters adjusting failed issue. Is there way where I can specify the constant camera parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this issue is related to not having the proper overlap(matching). Try to move the image less.

Comment: The overlap is there it is more than 40%